# Staytime resetting in foreach loop?

Tags: c#, foreach

the thing is `staytime` never goes to `0` but disconnection happens.

is `staytime` needed to be done something?

```
foreach (var playe in w_server.OnlineConnections)
{
        if (staytime > 1 * 20000 && play.Value.Map == "Rest")
        {
            staytime = Server.tickcount.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            w_server.Disconnect(play.Value.client.connection);
            play.Value.Map = "Village1";
            staytime = 0;
        }
}
```

Comment: what is `w_server` ? which API are you working on ?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on staytime to see if it fires

Comment: Is `staytime` meant to be a field of `playe`?

Comment: I assume that you declare staytime ahead of this shown code. Additionally do you think staytime = Server.tickcount.ElapsedMilliseconds should be before the if condition?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the variable `playe` to `play` in your `foreach` and then the `staytime` value assignment before the `if condition`. How could you make it `0` when you just assigned a value for `staytime`?

```
foreach (var play in w_server.OnlineConnections)
{
    staytime = Server.tickcount.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    if (staytime > 1 * 20000 && play.Value.Map == "Rest")
    {
        w_server.Disconnect(play.Value.client.connection);
        play.Value.Map = "Village1";
        staytime = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you put the Debug Break Point in staytime variable so that you will see what's the actual value of this and the variable play as well before it is compared using  if (staytime > 1 * 20000 && play.Value.Map == "Rest") ?